# Cut hole in volume generated from bezier curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

New to blender and I am having difficulty subtracting two objects from each other.

I have made a surface from a bezier curve which I extruded (using 2D under the geometry tab) and filled both ends. Now I want to cut a hole in both ends. So I made a cylinder with the correct diameter hoping that I could use boolean subtraction to remove the holes.

However when I select Add Modifier, Boolean doesn't even show up as an option.

Any thoughts on why that is/other ideas to try?

Comment: You can't add *Boolean* modifiers to curve objects directly, only to meshes, you would have to convert it first. Also a word of warning before it is too late: don't go down the Boolean road while modelling, learn proper modelling techniques or you will invariably regret it down the line for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: In the curve object's edit mode you can add new primitive curve shapes that will act in a subtractive/additive manner